# How do I edit /etc/rc.local?

Tags: shell-script

Im using Raspbian and trying to edit `/etc/rc.local`.

When I run `sudo nano etc/rc.local` or just `sudo nano rc.local` it creates a new file. And anything I try to edit in leafpad won't save.

Comment: Type the actual file name. Why are you typing only a part of it?

Answer (score 6):

You're forgetting the initial slash.

```
sudo nano -w /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: As an aside, there can be an issue with /etc/rc.local running if the OP is running `systemd`, e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/278396/systemd-does-not-run-etc-rc-local

Comment: Also, use `nano -w` to avoid the editor wrapping lines and breaking your file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Be sure you are in the right directory, /etc/. Eventually just cd into /etc/ to get an overview of everything you got in there, and then nano or vim (or what your prefered editor is) to the file from there :-)